# Create html table with increment number of column

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table

I have been success to make increment no on column.

Here my code

```css
table {
    counter-reset: rowNumber;
}
table tr {
    counter-increment: rowNumber;
}
table tr td:first-child::before {
    content: counter(rowNumber);
    min-width: 1em;
    margin-right: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>No</th> <th>Name</th>    
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td> <td>jhon</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td> <td>lucy</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td> <td>joe</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

[image]

but i want to make table number like image on below

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You must reset your counter on the second `<tr>`

```css
table tr:nth-child(2){
  counter-reset: rowNumber;
}
table tr {
  counter-increment: rowNumber;
}
table tr td:first-child::before {
  content: counter(rowNumber);
  min-width: 1em;
  margin-right: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>#</th> <th>Name</th>    
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td> <td>jhon</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td> <td>lucy</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td> <td>joe</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank a lot Alexis 
but when i implementation to table with pagination No. always reset to 1..
can you have solution ?

Comment: You make the same order of css property ? you don't have any class on your table ? You do you mean with pagination ? at the page the, the counter reset to 1 ?

Answer (score 0):

On the `table` element your counter is 1, on the first row it is incremented to 2. Hence starting at 2. You need to do the reset on the first `tr`.

```
table tr {
    counter-increment: rowNumber;
}
table tr:first {
    counter-reset: rowNumber;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Reset the counter at the second tr.

```css
tr:nth-child(2) {
  counter-reset: rowNumber;
}
table tr {
  counter-increment: rowNumber;
}
table tr td:first-child::before {
  content: counter(rowNumber);
  min-width: 1em;
  margin-right: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>No</th>
    <th>Name</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>jhon</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>lucy</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>joe</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: thank's a lot Nick..
but when i implementation to table with pagination No. always reset to 1..
can you have solution

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code to fix your issue. In your code you are counting the row number which is row number 2 in you case. so it is starting from 2.

One of the solution to your problem is use `thead` and `tbody` tags and increment the row counter from `tbody` as done it in below solution.

```css
table tbody {
    counter-reset: rowNumber;
}
table tbody tr {
    counter-increment: rowNumber;
}
table tr td:first-child::before {
    content: counter(rowNumber);
    min-width: 1em;
    margin-right: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<table border="1">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>No</th> <th>Name</th>    
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td></td> <td>jhon</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td> <td>lucy</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td> <td>joe</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank a lot Narendra  
but when i implementation to table with pagination No. always reset to 1..
can you have solution ?

Comment: What you are using for pagination?? Please share more info

Answer (score 0):

Just add -1 to the rowNumber

```
table {
    counter-reset: rowNumber-1;
}
table tr {
    counter-increment: rowNumber;
}
table tr td:first-child::before {
    content: counter(rowNumber);
    min-width: 1em;
    margin-right: 0.5em;
}
```